# Is there an Elgamal implementation in javascript?

Tags: implementation, elgamal-encryption

Does anyone know a good, well known implementation of ElGamal encryption and decryption in JavaScript? 
 
I was told that Stanford Javascript Crypto Library https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/ uses ElGamal but I am not sure about it. Does anyone know if they use it? 
 Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: 1. This is more of a software-recommendation question. 2. I would stick with ECIES and WebCrypto.

Comment: Huh, my brain must be going mush, I only see PBKDF2 to derive the symmetric keys for SJCL. Yep, brain is officially going... No asymmetric primitives whatsoever, and their paper is called "Symmetric Cryptography in Javascript" so that's pretty conclusive.